# How to loop through rows starting in row 2 and find out if row is empty from column E to column AE

Tags: vba

Basically I need to figure out how to loop through rows starting with row 2 column E to column AE and to the end of rows, find which ones are empty from column E over to column AE then place a letter code in that rows cell column d and place a different letter code if info is found in any cell in that selection (E thru AE) then of course move down one row and do the same until know info left in rows with column A as a reference on when to stop looping

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

Everything I have tried keeps blowing up, can't find a way to assign a value to multiple cell selections, at least that is how I have tried to attack this.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through Column E and if all cells in the active row to Column AE are empty it will put "E" in Column D of the active row, or a "F" in any cell has a value.

```
For Each cell In Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E" & cell.Row & ":" & "AE" & cell.Row)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Range("D" & cell.Row).Value = "E"
    Else 
        Range("D" & cell.Row).Value = "F"
    End If
Next cell
```